# Grant crawler account read access on all sites in collection?

Tags: search, permissions

I have a situation where permission inheritance is broken on a large number of sites. I'm trying to set up the Search Service App correctly so that it has its own crawling account which only has read access.

Is there a quick way to add read access to all sites in a collection without adding it manually (again: there are a lot of sites which break permission inheritance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Central Administration, go to Manage Web Applications. Highlight the desired Web Application hosting the Site Collections. Click on User Policy. Add a new account, input your crawler account, and provide it with Full Read access.

Policy rights bypass Site Collection permissions.